# How to monitor IBM Compose DB

Tags: mongodb, ibm-cloud, compose-db

I have an IBM Bluemix app. Bluemix created & deployed a Compose powered MongoDB for me. But I also have a seperate MongoDB deployment on **Compose** (http://compose.com).

Problem is, the Bluemix created version of MongoDB deployment has some issue I don't know. Because of this, I cannot use any other GUI tool such as **Robomongo** (https://robomongo.org), **MongoClient** to monitor the database. But most importantly, I cannot even use **mongoimport** CLI tool to import data.

So, if there's some way that I can either import the Bluemix created db into the Compose.io website or I can import / use Compose.io created DB into Bluemix, that would be great.

Comment: Unfortunately RoboMongo does not yet work with the new Compose MongoDB deployments when using SSL. Hopefully RoboMongo will push out an update with the arrival of MongoDB 3.2. Can you paste the exact `mongoimport` command you are trying (user credentials omitted)?

Comment: Yeah sure.


`mongoimport --host sl-us-dal-9-portal.3.dblayer.com --port 15741 --username < secret > --password < secret > --collection dummy --db admin --file ./appliances.json`

I spoke with a Compose team member yesterday. He said I cannot even use Compose deployed db in Bluemix or vice versa at this time.

Comment: What version of mongo do you have installed locally and what error message does that `mongoimport` command return?

Comment: Mongo CLI version 3.2.10 And the error is :

 **error connecting to db server: no reachable servers**

And the CA certificate that Bluemix provided me is invalid or in bad format. When I am using the --sslCAFile option along with the mongo CLI, it throws me an error :

**InvalidSSLConfiguration cannot read certificate authority file**

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you'll do. [There is guide on Mongo by BlueMix with reference with Node](https://www.ibm.com/blogs/bluemix/2015/04/reaching-enterprise-backend-bluemix-secure-gateway-via-sdk-api/), there is MongoDB UI written with Node. That is kind of official.

You can connect with other MongoDB UI (I mean full app) if you are using newest DB versions, your shell and DB management GUIs comply with the newest DB features including encryption. There is no official reference, you have to search whole earth, try and fail.

RoboMongo/Robo 3T does not work. You can ask on IBM DeveloperWorks to receive an official answer, [I guess you'll get response something like this](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/237617/accessing-mongodb-by-compose-dashboard/).

Answer (score 0):

The MongoDB Compose on Bluemix uses SSL. So to connect to it from RoboMongo or another tool you need to either use the certificate displayed on the mongoldb credentials screen or just use`unvalidated SSL`.

So if this is the blue mix mongoldb URI:

```
"uri": "mongodb://admin:KUGHDSBKJSLKNA@bluemix-sandbox-xxx-y-portal.z.dblayer.com:29802,bluemix-sandbox-....-dblayer.com:29802/compose?ssl=true&authSource=admin"
```

You use the following in your GUI Tool:

```
Hostname: bluemix-sandbox-xxx-y-portal.z.dblayer.com
Port: 29802
User: admin
Password: KUGHDSBKJSLKNA
AuthenticationDB: admin
SSL: Unvalidated.
```